# Finite Difference for Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman without boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-differences, optimal-control

Let $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ denote time, $x \in X$ is the state and $u \in U$ the control. The objective function is $F:X \times U \to\mathbb{R}$ and $f:X \times U \to\mathbb{R}$ is the law of motion for the state, i.e. 
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t))
\end{align}
Define the value function $v:X\to\mathbb{R}$ by 
\begin{align}
v(x_0):=\max_{\{u(t)\}_{t \geq 0}}\left[\int^\infty_0{e^{-\rho t}F(x(t),u(t))dt}\right]
\end{align}
where $x_0:=x(0)$ is a given initial condition and $\rho\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$
is a parameter (time preference rate). The [Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation) in current time reads
\begin{align}
\rho v(x) = \max_u[F(x,u) + v'(x)f(x,u)]
\end{align}
which is an ODE. If one can solve for $v(\cdot)$ we can recover the optimal path
\begin{align}
\{u^*(t):t\in\mathbb{R}_+\}  = \arg\max_{\{u(t)\}_{t \geq 0}}\left[\int^\infty_0{e^{-\rho t}F(x(t),u(t))dt}\right]
\end{align}
I try to solve the HJB equation by value function iteration. That is guessing an initial value function and then iterate until it converges to the true value. I update via an implicit method a la
\begin{align}
\frac{v_{j+1}(x_n)-v_j(x_n)}{\Delta} + \rho v_j(x_n) = F(x_n,u^*_n) + v'_{j+1}(x_n)f(x_n,u^*_n)
\end{align}
where $\Delta$ is a scaling paramter, $j=0,1,2,\ldots$ the number of iterations and $x_n$ an element of the grid of the state space
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} := [x_n]_{n=1}^N\in X^N
\end{align}
and $u_n$ is the solution of
\begin{align}
u^*_n = \arg\max_u [F(x_n,u_n) + v'_{j+1}(x_n)f(x_n,u_n)]
\end{align}

To get an expression for $v'(\cdot)$ we shall define slope coefficients by
\begin{align}
v'(x_n) :\approx
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_{n+1}) - v(x_n)}{\Delta x}\quad&\text{forward difference}\\[2mm]
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_{n+1}) - v(x_{n-1})}{2\Delta x}\quad&\text{central difference}\\[2mm]
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_n) - v(x_{n-1})}{\Delta x}\quad&\text{backward difference}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\Delta x$ denotes the equidistance between the elements of $\mathbf{x}$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\Delta x:=x_{n+1} - x_n = x_n - x_{n-1}~\forall n 
\end{align}

### Problem

It's known that for forward and backward difference one derivative is missing and for central difference two. We can deal with this issue by a boundary condition on either side. However, consider that there is no boundary condition given. I can still approx $v'(x)$ by a combination of forward, backward and central difference. For instance (case 1)
\begin{align}
v'(x_n) \approx
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_{n+1}) - v(x_n)}{\Delta x}\quad&n=1\\[2mm]
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_{n+1}) - v(x_{n-1})}{2\Delta x}\quad&1 < n <N\\[2mm]
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_n) - v(x_{n-1})}{\Delta x}\quad&n=N
\end{cases}
\end{align}

or (case 2)
\begin{align}
v'(x_n) \approx
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_{n+1}) - v(x_n)}{\Delta x}\quad&1\leq n <N\\[2mm]
\displaystyle\frac{v(x_n) - v(x_{n-1})}{\Delta x}\quad&n=N
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Note that in the second case $v'(x_{N-1})=v'(x_N)$.

- I was wondering what's common practice in the math profession.

I'm asking because I get significant different results for the different cases (irrespective of $N$).

PS: Note that I'm neither a mathematician nor a native english speaker. So I apologize for misunderstandigs.

Comment: It really depends what you're doing with $v'$.

Comment: I try to iterate a value function until it converges. Updating follows (implicit method) $v_{j+1}(k_n) - v_j(k_n) = f(k_n,v'_{j+1}(k_n),\cdot) $. Therefore I need to approx $v'(k_n)$.

Comment: Is this an ODE?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question by editing my orginial post.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as you. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no further hypotheses, there is no good numerical method to approximate the derivative.

Take for example
$$f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin\left(n^2x\right)$$
so
$$f'_n(x)=n\sin(n^2x)$$

Note that if you approximate $f$ to $0$ the error is $O(1/n)$, but if you approximate $f'$ to $0'=0$ the error is not even bounded.

Comment: This is a bit overstated. If you have no derivative bounds, then you can't know how fine your mesh needs to be and can't know how small your machine epsilon has to be. Nevertheless I can make the mesh fine enough and the machine epsilon small enough to handle your function for any particular $n$. For instance, if I take $n=10^{100}$ and make my machine epsilon $10^{-500}$, then I can handle your function just fine (with a small enough step size).